# Unable to find mspdbcore.dll when using FASTBuild distributed builds

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to compile our software using FASTBuild distributed builds. The general FASTBuild setup (derived from the actual setup within our company) can also be found on GitHub: https://github.com/SimonSchroeder/QMake2Fastbuild

We have recently switched from VS2013 with Qt 5.9.1 to VS2019 with Qt 5.13.2. Distributed builds work with the old setup, but fail with the new one. The error I get is:

```
c1xx: fatal error C1356: unable to find mspdbcore.dll
```

I have found the temporary directory where FASTBuild copies all mentioned files. This directory includes `mspdbcore.dll`. Even explicitly setting this path in the `PATH` environment variable or using a remote computer which also has VS2019 installed does not work.

Here is the excerpt from the `*.bff` file setting up the compiler:

```
Compiler( 'Compiler-VS2019-x64' )
{
    .Root       = '$VS2019_BasePath$/VC/Tools/MSVC/$VS2019_Version$/bin/Hostx64/x64'
    .Executable = '$Root$/cl.exe'
    .ExtraFiles = { '$Root$/c1.dll'
                    '$Root$/c1xx.dll',
                    '$Root$/c2.dll',
                    '$Root$/msobj140.dll'
                    '$Root$/mspdb140.dll'
                    '$Root$/mspdbcore.dll'
                    '$Root$/mspdbsrv.exe'
                    '$Root$/mspft140.dll'
                    '$Root$/msvcp140.dll'
                    '$Root$/vcruntime140.dll'
                    '$Root$/1033/clui.dll'
                  }

    ^VS_CL_EXE  = .Executable
}
```

Has anyone also experienced this problem? Is there any known solution to this problem? Any ideas what I could try?

I found this post related to problem of missing `mspdbcore.dll`: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/325122/c1356-unable-to-find-mspdbcoredll.html . However, it is supposed to be fixed with VS2019 version 16.1. My installed version is 16.3.9.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue in visual studio 16.3. Whether you downloaded the VS from the official platform? I suggest you could try to download and install the VS from [the official platform](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F). If it doesn't work, I suggest you post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problem. It all depends on the version in `$VS2019_Version$`. FASTBuild's own VS2019 configuration now contains `'$Root$/tbbmalloc.dll' // Required as of 16.2 (14.22.27905)` in `.ExtraFiles`. I was playing around with Version 14.23 which is larger than 14.22.

So, contrary to the error `mspdbcore.dll missing` it is other DLLs are missing instead.

Comment: You Sir are a gentleman and a scholar!
Here's the complete list of files for reference (VS 2019):
'$Root$/c1.dll'
'$Root$/c1xx.dll'
'$Root$/c2.dll'
'$Root$/atlprov.dll'
'$Root$/msobj140.dll'
'$Root$/mspdb140.dll'
'$Root$/mspdbcore.dll'
'$Root$/mspdbsrv.exe'
'$Root$/mspft140.dll'
'$Root$/msvcp140.dll'
'$Root$/tbbmalloc.dll'
'$Root$/vcruntime140.dll'
'$Root$/vcruntime140_1.dll'
'$Root$/1033/clui.dll'
'$Root$/1033/mspft140ui.dll'